# how to set the value of an option when using ng-options in a select with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options

I have a problem where I need to post the id field of a table to update a foreign-key of a record in the db, but I'm using the `ng-options` attribute to populate the select's options. I searched online and found that to set the value i had to use `ng-model="dataSet.desiredColumnName"` to change the value to which ever other column i choose

so I have this piece of html for the select;

```
<select id="affiliation" ng-model="affiliationTable.affiliation_id" ng-change="alert(jQuery('#affiliation option:selected').val());" name="affiliation" ng-options="row.desc for row in affiliationTable"></select>
```

the problem is, I want to make a specific option selected depending on which row in my html table is clicked on. the table is defined like this;

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in tableData">
    <!--{{row.name}}-->
    <td>
        <a href='#' ng-click="invokeModal(row);" id="{{row.id}}">{{row.name}}</a>
    </td>
    <td>{{row.active}}</td>
    <td>{{row.end_date}}</td>
    <td>{{row.start_date}}</td>
</tr>
```

and invokeModal uses the selected row to determine which option to select in select#affiliation;

```
$scope.invokeModal = function (row) { //memberDescription
    if(row == undefined){
        //blah blah ...
    }else{
        //blah blah ...
        angular.forEach($scope.affiliationTable, function (affiliation) {
            if (affiliation.id == row.affiliation_id) {
                $scope.affiliationTable.affiliation_id = affiliation.affiliation_id;
            }
        });
    }
        //invokes the modal window that select#affiliation is held within
    jQuery("#mem").modal('show');
};
```

my problem is that it seems as if it's adding an empty option in the beginning of the select and making that option selected. . .wtf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you ng-option expression needs to be corrected, it should be

```
row.id as row.desc for row in affiliationTable
```

The ng-model value on the select should be of same type when you assign the model property from code. You are assigning the id property of table, so on select the model should be updated with `id` property currently it being set to the full row object.

Comment: but if I do this wouldn't it make row.desc an alias and carry the value of row.id? I don't know if you've noticed, but I want the user to see row.desc, row.id is only the primary key and the value I'm using to update a foreign key in another table

Comment: Read the documentation on `ngOption` here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select you maybe making some mistake. See what expressions are allow and what they do.

Comment: Somewhere in the area where you are setting the ng-model for select do `{{dataSet.desiredColumnName}}` to output the selected value. Then go ahead and change the value from drop down. The output should change to new id.

Comment: what do you mean change the value of the drop down, can i say `$scope.affiliation = row.affiliation_id` ?

Comment: I mean from UI and see what does `dataSet.desiredColumnName}` get set to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38982/discussion-between-pythonian29033-and-chandermani)

Comment: ok, you were right, but my problem was that i was just setting it to a field that didn't exist
ie; I was using `affiliationTable[0].affiliation_id` and I should've used `affiliationTable[0].id`

thanks, got you 25rep for your trouble

Answer (score -1):

ng-options="value as label group by groupName for object in lists"

value can be any unique Identifier, label can be any text to display, groupname is the value based on which items need to be grouped and object is an object of the list on which traversing would be done.